# Regression. Optimize median instead of mean for skewed distribution

Tags: machine-learning

Let say I do the DNN regression task for some skewed data distribution.  Now I am using mean absolute error as loss function.

All typical approaches in machine learning are minimizing mean loss, but for skewed that is unappropriating. It is better from a practical point of view to minimize median loss. I think one way is to penalize big losses with some coefficient. And then mean will be close to the median. But how to calculate that coef for the unknown distribution type? Are there other approaches? What can you to advice?
(I am using tensorflow/keras)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the mean absolute error loss function in keras, instead of the mean squared.
The mean absolute is pretty much equivalent the median, and anyway would be more robust to outliers or skewed data. you should have a look at all of the possible keras losses:

https://keras.io/losses/

and obviously, you can create your own too.
But for most data sets it just empirically turns out that mean square gets you better accuracy. so i would recommend to at least try both methods before settling on the mean absolute one.

Comment: Thank you, Oren, I am already using absolute loss but in a tricky way. In the beginning, I am using squared loss, training model for some time before the loss became less than 1. After that, I am using abs loss. That works good. But still, it can be much better with appropriate loss calculation. Median error is still fluctuating, and mean is optimized as I can observe.

Comment: For most usecases, MAE / MSE are good, but for some usecases, situations like `|y_true - y_pred| = [0.1, ..., 0.1, 1000000000000]` are bad, and then medians, percentiles, or custom-made functions are much, much better.

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP tells us that the distribution is skewed so the mean and median absolute deviation are not similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you have skewed error distributions, you can use `tfp.stats.percentile` as your Keras loss function, with something like:

```
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    return tfp.stats.percentile(tf.abs(y_true - y_pred), q=50)
model.compile(loss=loss_fn)
```

It gives gradients, so works with Keras, although isn't as fast as MAE / MSE.

https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile

Comment: In the case the y_true and y_pred are tensors with 1 column then this returns a scalar. Is that an acceptable output for the loss function? Most examples I have seen return a vector of values.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing loss (/objective) functions is tough. Keras does theoretically allow you to do this, though they seem to have removed the documentation specifically describing it in their 2.0 release.

You can check their [docs on loss functions](https://keras.io/losses/#usage-of-loss-functions) for ideas, and then head over to the [source code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py) to see what kind of an API you should implement.

However, there are a number of [issues](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4920) filed by people who are having trouble with this, and the fact that they've removed the documentation on it is not inspiring.

Just remember that you have to use Keras own backend to compute your loss function. If you get it working, please write a blog post, or update with an answer here, because this is something quite a few other people have struggled/are struggling with!